# How to cache variables in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How does variable cacheing in node.js work?

**vars.js**

```
let V_SYNC_DATE;

export const SYNC_DATE = () => {

    if(!V_SYNC_DATE) {
        V_SYNC_DATE = new Date().toISOString();
    }
    return V_SYNC_DATE;
}
```

I have made this file vars.js that has a function SYNC_DATE and a variable V_SYNC_DATE . When someone calls the function it checks to see if the variable has not been set, if it hasen't it sets it to the current date and in either case it returns the variable. If I call this function multiple times the V_SYNC_DATE is always the same. I implemented this because that's exactly what i needed.

I'm just confused how this works, how is this variable being cached? Note: for this to work the variable needs to be declared outside of the function, otherwise the variable gets reinitialized and set every time.

Comment: If everyone has their own 'V_SYNC_DATE', why don't you create an object to store the `V_SYNC_DATE` for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you require a previously required file, the `exports` object is actually the cached one. That exports object would contain the pre-initialised global and static variables from the first `require()`.

As you have set `V_SYNC_DATE` outside of the export function, the variable will actually be treated as pertaining to the `vars.js` **module** and not the `SYNC_DATE` property of the module export object. So it will be subject to the `module caching`.

It is in fact not related to some sort of `variable caching`, as if you did this:

```js
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

  let V_SYNC_DATE;
  const SYNC_DATE = () => {

    if(!V_SYNC_DATE) {
        V_SYNC_DATE = new Date().toISOString();
    }
    return V_SYNC_DATE;
  }

  res.send(SYNC_DATE());
})
```

It would always return a new timestamp.

You can get rid of that cached module manually, by invoking:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('path/to/vars.js')]
```

So if you did this:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  let d = require('./path/to/vars.js');
  let a = d.SYNC_DATE();
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./path/to/vars.js')]
  res.send(a);
})
```

A new timestamp would always been returned, but if you get rid of your `delete` statement, then the cached timestamp would be returned.

I am not exactly sure how this behaviour works for your as indeed I don't know the details of your project, however, you will be able to control your module caching with `delete require.cache()`.

[Here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) you can read more about `require.cache()`

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the same date because you're checking for falsy value of `V_SYNC_DATE` and then setting it to the current date. For subsequent calls to `SYNC_DATE`, the falsy condition fails, thus `V_SYNC_DATE` is not updated to current date and it's returning the value which was set when the function was called the first time.